# Select dynamic cells based on content number format

Tags: excel, vba

I would need some help on the following excel 2010 vba:
I would like to select all cells which contain a specific number format. The cells can be located anywhere in column A.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify, number format and not cell formatting? What number format are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
Dim Tmp As String

Tmp = ""
For Each xx In Range("A1:A1000")
    If (xx.NumberFormat = "0") Then
        Tmp = Tmp & "," & xx.Address
    End If
Next
Tmp = Mid(Tmp, 2)
Range(Tmp).Select
```

select all the cells that have NumberFormat "0" ... Substitute the if stantement in base of your request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using the Range.Find method

```
Option Explicit
Sub CellsWithNumberFormat()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Const sFmt As String = "0.00" '<-- set to whatever numberformat you want
    Dim colAddr As Collection
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim I As Long
    Dim sTemp As String

Set R = Cells.Columns(1)
With Application.FindFormat
    .NumberFormat = sFmt
End With

Set colAddr = New Collection
With R
    Set C = .Find(what:="", LookIn:=xlValues, searchformat:=True)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        colAddr.Add Item:=C.Address
        sFirstAddress = C.Address
        Do
            Set C = .Find(what:="", after:=C, searchformat:=True)
            If C.Address <> sFirstAddress Then
                colAddr.Add Item:=C.Address
            End If
        Loop Until sFirstAddress = C.Address
    End If
End With

For I = 1 To colAddr.Count
    sTemp = sTemp & "," & colAddr(I)
Next I

sTemp = Mid(sTemp, 2)
Range(sTemp).Select

End Sub
```